# Equal height divs within containing element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here's my HTML (or just visit luxury-decor.co.uk)

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box_left">
        <p>Providing only the highest quality service work, both internal and external, in Reading, London and surrounding areas. We provide a bespoke service for any areas such as boardrooms, offices, showrooms, hotel lobby's, reception areas, bathrooms, wet rooms,
            kitchens and living areas. We specialise in Venetian Marble Plastering, Painting and Decorating, and both Wall & Floor Tiling. Our decorators are meticulous in what they do and we always strive to adhere to our customers needs. So whatever your project
            is, get in touch with us via email or telephone to discuss your requirements.
        </p>
    </div>
    <!--#box_left-->
    <div id="gallery_container1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.flashgallery('color_chart/gallery.swf', 'color_chart/config.xml', {
                width: '100%',
                background: '#000000'
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <!--#gallery_container1-->
</div>
<!--#wrapper-->
```

Now, as you can see the image gallery to the right is too large when set like this. Is it possible to make it so that the div's within the 'wrapper' are of equal heights? I did come across this http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/#.UUBcyhw0xnM but I am not too great with jQuery and could not get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS,

```
  div#wrapper > div{height:200px;}
```

Assuming you want 200px height for all div within wrapper

I hope this will do, if not reply :)

Comment: This would work, but I do not want to set a value for the height of my wrappers. I just want the #gallery_container1 to mirror the height of the .box_left

Comment: Then you may try JavaScript or jQuery--

$("#gallery_container1").height() = $(".box_left").height();

Comment: where would I put this code? & instead of having that, could I not put the flash object into the jquery so that the object size changes rather than the div?

Comment: I think that will be the same, flash object, while embedding, you need to specify the size !! :) so will be same,
put the above code in <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script> tag.
IF the page takes time the body tag>>onload>> call a function with this line. ITs Jquery , will go with in javascript . :)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
#wrapper { height: 400px; } //or whatever you like

#wrapper.box_left, #gallery_container1 { height: 100% }
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify the class/name of the wrappers, I don't know the flashgalley method so I can't help you with that, just look for the class/name of the divs it uses as wrappers, look into the html, then find the maximum height and set them all to that:

```
var wrappers = $('div.wrapper');
var maxHeight = 0;
for(var i in wrappers){
    if (maxHeight < wrappers[i].height()){
        maxHeight = wrappers[i].height();
    }
}
$('div.wrapper').height(maxHeight);
```

This will replicate the functionality of that plugin you linked to

Comment: How would I integrate this? In an external .js? I'm really not up to speed with my js

Comment: you can either use it inside <script></script> or in a js file if all the divs have the same name replace div.wrapper with div[name=thename] if all of them have the same class replace it with div.theclass